# How can I dynamically specify default value for DocbaseAttribute in DocbaseAttributeList in EMC Documentum WDK web application?

Tags: wdk, documentum, webtop, emc

I have docbaseattributelist on a page containing docbaseattributes. How can i dynamically (from inside of my web application) set default value for certain docbaseattribute of this list in EMC Documentum WDK application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends,
 if it is during import, then you can set a list of default values for the docbaseattribute controls via the Import component

in other cases you will need to extend the source docbaseattribute and when that value changes update the target docbaseattribute. Use an IVisitor to locate the target docbaseattribute, for example see how FindDirtyAttributeValue is used by the saving code